# TIBCO Spotfire: Cars in service since 3 weeks or more

Tags: crosstab, spotfire, tibco

I have a table of vehicles at service locations showing columns such as DAY, LICENSE, BOROUGH etc. I'd like to add a cross table showing the number of vehicles that have been serviced for 3 weeks or more. I'm not sure what custom expression to use.

Sample data:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RpzL.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Is there a from and to date column? Is there a record for each car for every day its in the shop? Is there a unique ID column? Knowing these things will help come up with a calculated column. I would look into using the `LastPeriods` function. This acts like `Lag` and needs a date column to work.

Comment: @MarkP.  sample data added

Comment: I don't see DATE, VEHICLE_NUMBER, or MODEL columns in your sample data as you mention in your question. I see no possible way to calculate "serviced for 3 weeks" based on the data you have provided.@konradbachusz

Comment: @AndrewPruet apologies. I changed the column names and provided more examples

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I still have no idea how to calculate "been serviced for 3 weeks or more". @konradbachusz

Comment: "Vehicle number" is probably the License, which should be unique enough along with date. So are you implying there are cars that have been in the shop for 21 days uninterrupted? And if a car was in the shop 20 days, left then came back for 20 more days, that wouldn't show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your sample data isn't containing a bunch of legitmate license plates. not the most compromising data but I would recommend blacking out or replacing them with test data if it isn't already.

anyway. you're looking for the `DateDiff()` function. for example:

```
If(DateDiff('day', Date(DateTimeNow()), [Date]) >= 21, "21 days or more", "less than 21 days")
```